# Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '[UIViewController]?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

In my app I was trying to do something like this:

```
class tabBarController : UITabBarController {

    ...

    func example (){
        let navController : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: calendarVC) //calendarVC is a UIViewController

        guard var VCs = self.viewControllers as [UIViewController]? else{
            self.setViewControllers([navController], animated: false)
            return
        }
        self.setViewControllers(VCs.append(navController), animated: false)
    }

    ...

}
```

But in the last line of the function I got an error:

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '[UIViewController]?

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` mutates the array rather than returning a new array with the value added. Split your last line into 2:

```
VCs.append(navController)
self.setViewControllers(VCs, animated: false)
```